# Maps API requires additional permissions that have already been set

Tags: android, google-maps, android-keystore

I've set up a map view using the following steps:

- Got my API key, turned on maps and Google play services access.
- Added entry for sha1 fingerprint (from debug.store) and app package name.
- Created manifest as follows:

**Manifest:**

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="$$MY_KEY_IS_HERE$$"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

**And when running the Activity that contains the map, I get:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Obviously I've set these permissions, so how can I find out what is really wrong?**

Comment: have you getting problem to load map????

Comment: what's your package name?

Comment: @Pankaj package name is 'iceberg.infiniti.app'. Its set in build.gradle, Android.manifest and now the java package names match too.

Comment: you mean to say that you've changed package name in <Permission> also which looks like this :  android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps

Comment: @Pankaj - I think you've spotted it. Thanks! Testing. . .

Comment: Hmmm, actually no change.

Comment: strange behaviour!! try to search if there's something similar error that you did last time

Comment: @Pankaj You were right after all, not sure why it didn't work the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"

with

android:name="iceberg.infiniti.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"

Hope this helps.